# Class function is defined but not to be called(C++)

Tags: c++, function, class

I want to call a public function from the class "hello" but this error won't let me. Please tell me what am i doing wrong?

*Here's the code:*

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

class hello {
    public: 
        void sayit(){
            cout << "Hello, World!";
        }
    };

int main(){
    string str;
    cout << "Type in \"start\":";
    cin >> str;
    if (str == "start"){
//this is where the error happens.
        hello.sayit();
    }
}
```

*This is the error:*

> [Error] expected unqualified-id before '.' token

Comment: You need to either make sayIt() static or declare a hello object and then call the method

Answer (score 1):

You need to either make `sayIt()` `static` or declare a `hello` object and then call the `method`. The static method would look like `static void sayIt()` and you call it like `hello.sayIt()` as static methods do not need an instance of the class to work. If you use a `hello` object it would be done like this `hello x; x.sayIt()`.

Comment: Recommend adding a demonstration of how to call the static function since it is a bit different from what the asker is attempting.

Comment: @user4581301 I add this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`void sayit()` defines a class member function.

To invoke a class member function, you need an instance of the class.

```
hello hello_instance;
hello_instance.sayit();
```

As an alternative you can change `sayit` to a static function. A static function is a member of the class but does not require an instance of the class. As a result the `this` variable is not present in a `static` method and non-static member variables cannot be used.

```
static void sayit(){
    cout << "Hello, World!";
}
```

Does not use any member variables and can be called with

```
hello::sayit();
```